# I want to generate a compile warning for JPA annotations with a given value

Tags: java, jpa, aspectj

I just finished reading AspectJ in Action and am trying to write some simple aspects to start with. I would like to write an aspect that will generate a compile-time warning for fields that use `EnumType.ORDINAL` to persist to the database, but not for those that use `EnumType.STRING`. I've written similar aspects, but this is the first one I'm trying that uses an annotation in the pointcut, and I'm doing something wrong.

I have a JPA2.1 entity like the one shown below, and would like the `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)` annotation attached to `myEnumFieldB` to generate a compiler warning...

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;

@Entity
public class myEntity {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) // I want this to compile ok
    protected MyEnumType myEnumFieldA;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) // I want this to throw a warning
    protected MyEnumType myEnumFieldB;

    // primary key, other fields, getters & setters, etc. omitted
}
```

...and here's a copy of my code trying several different pointcuts (commented out), with the error messages included beside them. The named pointcut is only used by the last commented-out line.

```
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;

public aspect DetectEnumPersistencePolicy {
    pointcut ordinalEnumPersistence(Enumerated enumerated)
        : @annotation(enumerated) && if(enumerated.value() == EnumType.ORDINAL);
        // used below in a commented-out pointcut

    declare warning
        : @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
        //ERROR: Syntax error on token "Enumerated", "pointcut name" expected

        //: @javax.persistence.Enumerated(javax.persistence.EnumType.ORDINAL)
        //ERROR: Syntax error on token "javax", "pointcut name" expected

        //: @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) * *.*
        //ERROR: Syntax error on token "Enumerated", "pointcut name" expected

        //: execution(@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) * *.*)
        //ERROR: Syntax error on token ")", "(" expected

        //: ordinalEnumPersistence(enumerated)
        // ERROR: if() pointcut designator cannot be used in declare statement

        : "Please consider using string persistence of enumerated types instead.";
}
```

My thoughts so far are:

1. When I tried including `if(enumerated.value() == EnumType.ORDINAL)` the error message was `if() pointcut designator cannot be used in declare statement`. This made me think that I can't use a pointcut with an `if()` because that would be evaluated at runtime but the `warning` needs to be generated at compile time (even though the data is all there at compile time because the annotation's value doesn't vary with the runtime state)?
2. Same for `execution(@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) * *.*)` because execution occurs at runtime. The error message `Syntax error on token ")", "(" expected` didn't mean much to me (it's referring to the second `)`).
3. If I just use `@annotation(enumerated)` it should work at compile-time, but then I don't know how to perform the check `enumerated.value() == EnumType.ORDINAL` before throwing the warning?
4. I've tried using the fully qualified names in the pointcut `@javax.persistence.Enumerated(javax.persistence.EnumType.ORDINAL)` but still got the error message `Syntax error on token "javax", "pointcut name" expected`.
5. I tried appending some asterisks to the annotation in the pointcut to specify that I'm referring to a field `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) * *.*` but still got the error message `Syntax error on token "Enumerated", "pointcut name" expected`.

For completeness, I'm working in Spring Tool Suite 3.7.2 with Java 1.8 and using Maven to manage the following AspectJ dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjlib</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated - I can't see why `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you have a basic problem: There is no pointcut catching member declarations, only for read/write access on members. I am talking about `get()` and `set()`, respectively. Consequently, what you want to intercept are those. Try this:

**Dummy helper class to make the sample code compile:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class MyEnumType {}
```

**Java class with annotated members plus main method demonstrating the aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) // I want this to compile ok
    protected MyEnumType myEnumFieldA;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) // I want this to throw a warning
    protected MyEnumType myEnumFieldB;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
        myEntity.myEnumFieldA = new MyEnumType();
        System.out.println(myEntity.myEnumFieldB);
    }
}
```

As you can see, `myEnumFieldB` is accessed once in the last line. This should throw a compiler warning.

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;

public aspect DetectEnumPersistencePolicy {
    pointcut ordinalEnumPersistence() :
        set(@Enumerated(value=EnumType.ORDINAL) * *) ||
        get(@Enumerated(value=EnumType.ORDINAL) * *);

    declare warning : ordinalEnumPersistence() :
        "Please consider using string persistence of enumerated types instead.";
}
```

This is what you will see in Eclipse:

[image: Eclipse compiler warning]